# Identify which button is clicked among 91 buttons using TornadoFX

Tags: tornadofx

Is there an easy way to create multiple buttons (Say 81 buttons for Sudoku game),each with different text, using TornadoFX (not javaFX).  Once created, how to identify which button is clicked and then provide a unique event handler of the button clicked?  Same question, using textArea instead of button.

Answer (score 0):

```
gridpane {
    for (i in 0..8) {
        for (j in 0..8) {
            // Put your own number here, based on i,j coordinates
            val button = Button("$i, $j")
            button.setOnAction {
                buttonClicked(i, j)
            }
            add(button, i, j)
        }
    }
}
```

And the appropriate function:

```
fun buttonClicked(row: Int, column: Int) {
    // Do your stuff here, printing is just an example
    print("row:$row, column:$column")
}
```

Notice that it isn't leveraging any of the TornadoFX capabilities, except using the `gridpane` function, so it could possibly be improved.

Comment: An alternative solution would be to set a property on the button and pass the button itself to the click handler.

Comment: Thank you for your interesting in this problem and your prompt reply.  While this is a candidate solution and you are absolutely right, the solution has not yet fully leverage the power of TornadoFX.

Comment: Would you please clarity the alternative solution to set a property on the button and pass the button itself to the click handler ?  Each button would have a text of one digit with a large font and up to nine digits with small fonts using inline CSS.